# Why is my function returning the wrong value on certain conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function named getFirstPlayer. The user must enter either B (for black) or W (for white).

Everything works as intended, but only when an accepted value is initially entered. Unaccepted values (anything other than W, w, B, b) are recognized and the function is called again, and then when a user inputs an accepted value, nothing is returned.

For example:

`A
Specify which player will move first: B for black, W for white
C
Specify which player will move first: B for black, W for white
B`

Returned value: None

However, when you input "B" on the first try, the integer 1 is correctly returned.

```
def getFirstPlayer() -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            firstPlayer = str(input())

            if firstPlayer == 'W' or firstPlayer == 'w':
                return 2
            elif firstPlayer == 'B' or firstPlayer == 'b':
                return 1
            else:
                print("Specify which player will move first: B for black, W for white")
                getFirstPlayer()

        except ValueError:
            print("Specify which player will move first: B for black, W for white")
            continue
        else:
            break
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`None` is the value that gets returned when nothing else is, which is the case on the last `else` clause in the `try` block. Try:

```
def getFirstPlayer() -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            firstPlayer = str(input())

            if firstPlayer == 'W' or firstPlayer == 'w':
                return 2
            elif firstPlayer == 'B' or firstPlayer == 'b':
                return 1
            else:
                print("Specify which player will move first: B for black, W for white")
                return getFirstPlayer() # changed this line

        except ValueError:
            print("Specify which player will move first: B for black, W for white")
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Learned something as well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you ever enter the `else` clause in your `try` block, nothing is returned.

(This is not really something you should be using recursion for.)

A more sensible function would look like this:

```
def getFirstPlayer() -> int:
    while True:
        firstPlayer = input("Specify which player will move first: B for black, W for white: ")
        if firstPlayer in ('W','w'):     # One way to handle upper- and lowercase
            return 2
        elif firstPlayer.lower() == 'b': # Another way 
            return 1
```